# Placing a where clause at end of SQL statement using codeigniter's active record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to create an `SQL` statement using codeingniter's active record that resembles something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`posts`)
JOIN `Post_images` ON `Post_images`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
WHERE `title`  LIKE '% $SEARCHTERM %'
OR  `content`  LIKE '% $SEARCHTERM %'
AND `location` =  ' $LOCATION '
GROUP BY `posts`.`id`
```

My PHP is currently:

```
$this->db->like('title', $term);

$this->db->or_like('content', $term);

$this->db->group_by('posts.id');

$this->db->join('Post_images', 'Post_images.post_id = posts.id');

$query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('location' => $location));

return $query->result_array();
```

The query this PHP is generating is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`posts`)
JOIN `Post_images` ON `Post_images`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
WHERE `location` =  ' $LOCATION '
AND  `title`  LIKE '% $SEARCHTERM %'
OR  `content`  LIKE '% $SEARCHTERM %'
GROUP BY `posts`.`id`
```

As the `OR` statement is at the end if a match is found in the 'content' column the location is completely ignored.

Is there anyway to ensure that the `WHERE` statement is placed after the `OR` statement?

Comment: I've found it easier to just write you query like you want it to be and do query binding with code igniter for more complex queries. Bottom of http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$this->db->like('title', $term);
$this->db->or_like('content', $term);
$this->db->where('location = ', $location);
$this->db->group_by('posts.id');
$this->db->join('Post_images', 'Post_images.post_id = posts.id');
$query = $this->db->get('posts');

return $query->result_array();
```

This will reproduce your expected query, but i think you are wanting something like this to work ok:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`posts`)
JOIN `Post_images` ON `Post_images`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
WHERE (`title`  LIKE '% $SEARCHTERM %'
OR  `content`  LIKE '% $SEARCHTERM %')
AND `location` =  ' $LOCATION '
GROUP BY `posts`.`id`
```

attention to parenthesis i added

to do this with active record, you will need to pass a `string` to where method, like this:

```
$this->db->where("(`title` LIKE '% $term %' || `content` LIKE '% $term %')");
$this->db->where('location = ', $location);
$this->db->group_by('posts.id');
$this->db->join('Post_images', 'Post_images.post_id = posts.id');
$query = $this->db->get('posts');

return $query->result_array();
```

Let me know if this work

Comment: Thanks, not only did you anticipate what I actually needed you provided a working solution!